# Log all arguments to RegExp or //

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

For debugging (using puppeteer/headless Chrome), I want to log all regular expression patterns of a page (eg, all arguments to `new RegExp()`, `//`). I could replace `window.RegExp` with my own function, but that won't catch `/pattern/` regexes. How to proceed?

**Update**: the awesome answer, thanks to @vlaz, is this:

```
var regex = /abc/;

origtest = RegExp.prototype.test;
RegExp.prototype.test = function (p, f) {
    process.stdout.write(this + "\n");
    return origtest.apply(this, arguments);
};

console.log(regex.test("bla"));
```

Can't use console.log in the replacement function, because console.log itself uses RegExp.

Comment: You..don't. It's not possible to override the literal constructors. Same goes for `[]` or `{}` - they always result with a new base Array or Object respectively, regardless of whether `Array` or `Object` are overwritten.

Comment: Thanks. Could I somehow replace RegExp.prototype.compile instead?

Comment: You could replace `.test` and `.match` to print `this` then return the result of the original function. But this will produce A LOT of log noise. It has the potential to change how regex works ever so slightly. Also, I'm not sure what it accomplishes - why would you need to see every single regex used on a page? Presumably you want it to check for errors or something but it's better to unit test what you're not sure of.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Added solution to my question.

Comment: You don't want to `return false` because otherwise no regex would ever match. You need something like `origTest = RegExp.prototype.test` to save the function and to replace it by still calling the original functionality `RegExp.prototype.test = function() { process.stdout.write(this); return origTest.apply(this, arguments) }`. If you also replace `.match` in the same manner, that means that you'd get output for stuff like `someString.replace(/regex/, "replacement");`